# strcpy giving segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, strcpy

Hi please help me with this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int classmatesize=0;
char **classmate1;
char **classmate2;    

void checkclassmates(){
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<classmatesize;i++){
            for(j=i+1;j<classmatesize;j++){
                if(strcmp(classmate1[i],classmate1[j])==0){
                    strcpy(classmate1[classmatesize],classmate2[i]);
                    strcpy(classmate2[classmatesize],classmate2[j]);
                    classmatesize++;
                }else if(strcmp(classmate1[i],classmate2[j])==0){
                    strcpy(classmate1[classmatesize],classmate2[i]);
                    strcpy(classmate2[classmatesize],classmate1[j]);
                    classmatesize++;                
                }else if(strcmp(classmate2[i],classmate2[j])==0){
                    strcpy(classmate1[classmatesize],classmate1[i]);
                    strcpy(classmate2[classmatesize],classmate1[j]);
                    classmatesize++;
                }else if(strcmp(classmate2[i],classmate1[j])==0){
                    strcpy(classmate1[classmatesize],classmate1[i]);
                    strcpy(classmate2[classmatesize],classmate2[j]);
                    classmatesize++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
int main(void) {
    int i;

    classmate1 = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char*));
    for ( i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
    classmate1[i] = malloc((1000) * sizeof(char));

    classmate2 = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char*));
    for ( i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
    classmate2[i] = malloc((1000) * sizeof(char));


    yyparse();
    checkclassmates();
    print_the_array();
    return 0;
}
```

my yyparse(); if i print the classmate1 and classmate2 by commenting the checkclassmates function its printing and clasematesize is printing as 7

```
classmate1
[ sania  pawan  pandu  haldiram  manas  abhi  prince ]
classmate2
[ sam  pandu  madhur  arjun  jyoti  ash  sam ]
```

proplem is with strcpy only if i comment the strcpy instructions its working fine its giving segmentation fault.
i even tried sprintf instead of strcpy still i cannot figure it out.

Comment: What does `yyparse` do?

Comment: show us **yyparse();** and **print_the_array();**

Comment: @Michi Because `classmate1` is a pointer to **pointers**, not to `char`s.

Comment: @cad my bad :). I didn't noticed.

Comment: if the input is "a is classmateof b" .yyparse(); will add a to classmate1 and b to classmate2 @cad

Answer (score 5):

My hunch is that the lines

```
                classmatesize++;
```

in `checkclassmates` are the culprits. There are four of them. Since you are are incrementing `classmatesize` inside the loops, the conditional of the `if` statements never fail and you end up accessing the arrays out of bounds.

Try removing those lines and see whether the problem is still there.

Comment: Without seeing what `classmatesize` is set to other than its initial value of zero, I don't even see how those loops run - `i` starts as zero, which isn't less than the initial value of `classmatesize`.  There's code missing.

Comment: when i am adding the elements into the array , at that time only  i am doing classmatesize++. so i am just keeping the track of array size